# Create CSV from API output

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv, for-loop

I am trying to create an CSV file from some API call's i do with python.

I already got it working but it is not a very practical way to solve my problem.

Basically what i am trying to do is this:

```
    csv_headers = ['Switch','Switchport Number','Port Name','VLAN']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=csv_headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    get_devices = requests.get(base_url + '/networks/' + net_id + '/devices/', headers=headers).json()#Get all devices
    for device in get_devices:
        model = device['model']
        if 'MS' in model:
            serial = device['serial']
            name = device['name']
            switch_info = requests.get(base_url + '/devices/' + serial + '/switchPorts', headers=headers).json()#Get SwitchPortNumber, SwitchPortName and VLAN
            for switch_item in switch_info:
                switch_port = switch_item['number']
                switch_port_name = switch_item['name']
                vlan = switch_item['vlan']
                writer.writerow({csv_headers[0]:name,csv_headers[1]:switch_port,csv_headers[2]:switch_port_name,csv_headers[3]:vlan})

csv_headers2 = ['Switch Port','IP Address','Mac Address','Manufactor']
    writer2 = csv.DictWriter(csv_file2, fieldnames=csv_headers2)
    writer2.writeheader()
    get_client = requests.get(base_url + '/devices/' + serial + '/clients?timespan=180', headers=headers).json()
    for client_item in get_client:
        ip = client_item['ip']
        mac = client_item['mac']
        sp = int(client_item['switchport'])
        vendor = requests.get('https://api.macvendors.com/' + client_item['mac'])
        vendor = (format(str(vendor.text)))
        vendor = vendor.replace(",","")
        time.sleep(1)
        writer2.writerow({csv_headers2[0]:sp,csv_headers2[1]:ip,csv_headers2[2]:mac,csv_headers2[3]:vendor})
#CREATE CLIENT OUTPUT CSV#

#CREATE DATAFRAMES AND RENAME COLUMNS#
df1 = pd.read_csv(dirname+'/temp_switch.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(dirname+'/temp_client.csv')
df2.rename(columns={"Switch Port": "Switchport Number"}, inplace=True)
#CREATE DATAFRAMES AND RENAME COLUMNS#

#MERGE DATAFRAMES#
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["Switchport Number"], how="left")
#MERGE DATAFRAMES#

#REPLACE NO VALUES WITH DEFAULT VALUES#
default_values = {"IP Address": "No IP Address found", "Mac Address": "No MAC Address found", "Manufactor": "Could not resolve vendor"}
merged_df.fillna(value=default_values, inplace=True)
#REPLACE NO VALUES WITH DEFAULT VALUES#

#CREATE FINAL OUTPUT CSV
merged_df.to_csv(dirname+'/SwitchOutput-'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y-%H-%M-%S")+'.csv', index=False)
#CREATE FINAL OUTPUT CSV

#REMOVE TEMP FILES#
os.remove(dirname+'/temp_switch.csv')
os.remove(dirname+'/temp_client.csv')
```

As you can see i am trying to make some API call's and 'store' that data in a temp csv file. search that data and if the switchport has an IP, combine that data, if != then just print No data found.

Can i store my data in a DataFrame from pandas maybe? Something like

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = ['Switch','Switchport Number','Port Name','VLAN',IP Address','Mac Address','Manufactory']



df1 = pd.DataFrame(output from switch_info)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(output from client_info)

compare data from df1 with df2 and create df3

merged_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Hopefully someone can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, i am assuming you have a proper JSON response from your API. 
For this you can create your 2 dataframes using

```
get_devices = requests.get(base_url + '/networks/' + net_id + '/devices/', headers=headers).json()#Get all devices
get_client = requests.get(base_url + '/devices/' + serial + '/clients?timespan=180', headers=headers).json()
df1 = pd.read_json(get_devices)
df2 = pd.read_json(get_client)
```

and apply respective operations such as

```
df1 = df1[df1['model'=='MS']]
```

and so on with join between device and client.